# Google Apps Script MailApp change Sender Name

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I want to change the sender name of my outgoing mails. My code looks like this:

```
var emailAddress = sheet.getRange("D").getValue();
    var name = sheet.getRange("E").getValue();
    var personalizedMessage = Utilities.formatString(message, name);

    if (emailAddress) {
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, personalizedMessage, {name: "Orthoback"});
    }
  }
```

Which matches (in my opinion) to the google documentation of the class MailApp:

```
MailApp.sendEmail('mike@example.com', 'Attachment example', 'Two files are attached.', {
    name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), blob]
});
```

Unfortunately, the sender name remains the same. It's still just the sender mail address. Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `Unfortunately, the sender name remains the same. It's still just the sender mail address.`, which do you want to change the sender name or the sender email address?

Comment: Originally I wanted to change the senders mail address, but it seemed like too much effort. So I just want to change the sender name now.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I had posted an answer by guessing your expected result. I apologize for this. About `So I just want to change the sender name now.`, I think that your showing script can be achieved. If that cannot be done, please try to change Class MailApp to Class GmailApp and test it again. And, in order to change both sender's name and the sender's email address, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying. First, I apologize for the inconvenience. And, unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script, I confirmed that both the sender's email and the sender's name can be changed. So, I proposed this. I apologize for this situation. But, you say `I wanted to say, that the sender name is by default the sender email address. And my goal is to change the sender name to 'Orthoback'. I tried your script, but the sender name as well as the sender email address is still the same, it didn't work.`. In this case, I'm worried that your situation might be different from mine.

Comment: I believe that you tried my all proposed methods. For example, when your account is included in Google Workspace, your goal might depend on the setting by the administrator. But, from your question, I cannot know about it. So, in this case, I think that my answer was not useful. So, I have to delete my answer. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Which matches (in my opinion) to the google documentation of the class MailApp:`
Regrettably this is a not correct.

The variable `name` appears several times in the script:

- `var name = sheet.getRange("E").getValue();`
- `var personalizedMessage = Utilities.formatString(message, name);`
- `{name: "Orthoback"}`

The sender name is NOT being changed because of the duplicated `name` variable.

The solution is to change the variable name used in the Personalised message.
For example:

- `var messageName = sheet.getRange("E1").getValue();`
- `var personalizedMessage = Utilities.formatString(message, messageName);`
- `{name: "Orthoback"}`

This will result in "Othoback" being displayed as the sender.

---

**Sample**

[image: sender name]